# Log Factory error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate on Eclipse and continually get the following error message when I try to compile:

> build.xml:39: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

I have the `commons-logging.jar` file inside my libs folder, and here is my classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="flex_src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

I even tried printing the class path from within the `build.xml` file, and the `commons-logging.jar` appears within there as well, with the correct directory. Here is my build.xml file for further reference:

```
<project name="project" default="main">
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <xmlproperty file="${project-root}/src/META-INF/persistence.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
    <description>Generate CDB files</description>
    <target name="force">
        <property name="force.build" value="true" />
        <antcall target="mainInternal" />
    </target>
    <target name="main">
        <property name="force.build" value="false" />
        <antcall target="mainInternal" />
    </target>
    <target name="mainInternal">
        <antcall target="generateHibernateCfg" />
        <antcall target="compileEntities" />
        <antcall target="findAnnotations" />
        <antcall target="compileServiceInterfaces" />
        <antcall target="generateDTOs" />
        <antcall target="generateServices" />
        <antcall target="generateFlex" />
        <antcall target="generateBlazeDSConfig" />
    </target>
    <target name="generateHibernateCfg">
        <xslt in="${project-root}/src/META-INF/persistence.xml" style="${project-root}/cdb_build/src/hibernate.cfg.xsl" out="${project-root}/src/hibernate.cfg.xml" force="${force.build}" />
    </target>
    <target name="compileEntities">
        <path id="build.class.path">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <pathelement path="${classes-folder}" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="cp" refid="build.class.path" />
        <echo message="Classpath = ${cp}"/>
        <path id="srcfiles">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="srcfiles" refid="srcfiles" pathsep=" " />
        <script language="javascript">
            <![CDATA[
            var includes = "";
            var entitiesString = project.getProperty("persistence.persistence-unit.class");
            if (entitiesString) {
                var entities = entitiesString.split(",");
                for (entity in entities) {
                    if (entities[entity] != null && entities[entity] != "") {
                        includes += String(entities[entity]).replace(/\./g, '/') + ".java,";
                    }
                }
            }
            project.setProperty("entities.include", includes);
            ]]>
        </script>
        <mkdir dir="${project-root}/build/classes" />
        <javac includes="${entities.include}" srcdir="${project-root}/src" destdir="${classes-folder}" classpath="${cp}" debug="on" />
    </target>
    <target name="findAnnotations">
        <file name="annotated.xml" id="annotated.xml" />
        <echo file="annotated.xml" message="&lt;annotated-types/&gt;" />
        <path id="build.class.path">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <pathelement path="${classes-folder}" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="cp" refid="build.class.path" />
        <path id="srcfiles">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="srcfiles" refid="srcfiles" pathsep=" " />
        <path id="cfg-xml-path">
            <fileset file="${project-root}/src/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="cfg-xml" refid="cfg-xml-path" />
        <apt classpath="${cp}" 
            compile="false"
            factory="com.farata.cdb.annotations.processor.CDBFullAnnotationProcessor"
            srcdir="${project-root}/src"
            sourcepath="${project-root}/src">
            <option name="com.faratasystems.cdb.annotations.file" value="annotated.xml"/>
            <option name="com.faratasystems.cdb.configuration.file" value="${cfg-xml}"/>
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </apt>
    </target>
    <target name="compileServiceInterfaces">
        <path id="build.class.path">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <pathelement path="${classes-folder}" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="cp" refid="build.class.path" />
        <path id="srcfiles">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="srcfiles" refid="srcfiles" pathsep=" " />
        <xmlproperty file="annotated.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
        <script language="javascript">
            <![CDATA[
            var includes = "";
            var typeNamesString = project.getProperty("annotated-types.annotated-type.name");
            if (typeNamesString) {
                var annotationNamesString = project.getProperty("annotated-types.annotated-type.annotations.annotation.name");
                var annotationNames = annotationNamesString.split(",");
                var typeNames = typeNamesString.split(",");
                for (annotationName in annotationNames) {
                    if (annotationNames[annotationName] != null && annotationNames[annotationName] != "") {
                        if (annotationNames[annotationName] == "clear.cdb.annotations.CX_Service") {
                            includes += String(typeNames[annotationName]).replace(/\./g, '/') + ".java,";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            project.setProperty("entities.include", includes);
            ]]>
        </script>
        <javac includes="${entities.include}" srcdir="${project-root}/src" destdir="${classes-folder}" classpath="${cp}" debug="on" />
    </target>
    <target name="generateDTOs">
        <xmlproperty file="annotated.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
        <path id="build.class.path">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <pathelement path="${classes-folder}" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="cp" refid="build.class.path" />
        <path id="srcfiles">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="srcfiles" refid="srcfiles" pathsep=" " />
        <xslt classpathref="build.class.path" in="annotated.xml" style="src/service-dto-all.xsl" out="tmp.txt" force="true">
            <param name="outputFolder" expression="${project-root}src" />
            <param name="force" expression="${force.build}" />
        </xslt>
        <script language="javascript" src="${basedir}/scripts.js">
            <![CDATA[
                var includes = getServicesDTOs();
                includes += getServicesDTOSubclasses();
                project.setProperty("entities.include", includes == ""? "none":includes);
            ]]>
        </script>
        <javac includes="${entities.include}" srcdir="${project-root}/src" destdir="${classes-folder}" classpath="${cp}" debug="on" failonerror="false" />
    </target>
    <target name="generateServices">
        <xmlproperty file="annotated.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
        <path id="build.class.path">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <pathelement path="${classes-folder}" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="cp" refid="build.class.path" />
        <path id="srcfiles">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="srcfiles" refid="srcfiles" pathsep=" " />
        <xslt classpathref="build.class.path" in="annotated.xml" style="src/service-impl-all.xsl" out="tmp.txt" force="true">
            <param name="outputFolder" expression="${project-root}src" />
            <param name="force" expression="${force.build}" />
        </xslt>
        <script language="javascript" src="${basedir}/scripts.js">
            <![CDATA[
            var includes = getServices();
            includes += getServicesSubclasses();
            project.setProperty("entities.include", includes == ""? "none":includes);
            ]]>
        </script>
        <javac includes="${entities.include}" srcdir="${project-root}/src" destdir="${classes-folder}" classpath="${cp}" debug="on" />
    </target>
    <target name="generateFlex">
        <xmlproperty file="annotated.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
        <path id="build.class.path">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <pathelement path="${classes-folder}" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="cp" refid="build.class.path" />
        <path id="srcfiles">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="srcfiles" refid="srcfiles" pathsep=" " />
        <xslt classpathref="build.class.path" in="annotated.xml" style="flex_src/flex-all.xsl" out="tmp.txt" force="true">
            <param name="flexOutputFolder" expression="${flex-output-folder}" />
            <param name="javaSrcFolder" expression="${project-root}src" />
            <param name="force" expression="${force.build}" />
        </xslt>
        <xslt classpathref="build.class.path" in="annotated.xml" style="flex_src/application-all.xsl" out="tmp.txt" force="true">
            <param name="javaSrcFolder" expression="${project-root}src" />
            <param name="testFolder" expression="${project-root}test" />
            <param name="force" expression="${force.build}" />
        </xslt>
    </target>
    <target name="generateBlazeDSConfig">
        <xmlproperty file="annotated.xml" collapseAttributes="true" />
        <path id="build.class.path">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <pathelement path="${classes-folder}" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="cp" refid="build.class.path" />
        <path id="srcfiles">
            <fileset dir="${project-root}/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <pathconvert property="srcfiles" refid="srcfiles" pathsep=" " />
        <script language="javascript" src="${basedir}/scripts.js">
            <![CDATA[
            generateRemotingConfig();
            generateMessagingConfig();
            ]]>
        </script>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to provide more details on your project structure. How did you package your project? (Does it contain an ear with ejb module packaged...)

Pretty obviously its a class loading problem. Or it is possible that the jar is not packaged with the final deployable archive. The easiest fix for your solution is to copy and paste the common-logging.jar file in to your server's lib directory. (for tomcat I believe its under catalina_home folder.. but I am not sure)

Comment: Unfortunately, I had already tried copy-pasting the jar into the server's lib directory earlier with no luck

Comment: How do you deploy this project in your server? Did you open up the deployable archive? (unzip it..) Did you find the common.loggin.jar then. May be you have a different version of the jar file. Could you also open up the common.logging.jar file and see if the package "org.apache.common.logging" exists.

Comment: The package does indeed exist in the jar file. I'm also not sure what you mean by deployable archive. I'm getting these errors during the offline building of the file, without ever getting Tomcat involved. Wouldn't that preclude it from being a server issue?

Comment: I am sorry. Without enough information, It just became an activity of shooting in the dark . Apparently eclipse build path seems to be able to identify the jar file, but ant build fails with this error. The only thing I could suggest is to check your build path in eclipse ( right click -> build path) and see if it looks up the same one used by ant (webcontent --> lib .. right?). Also please make sure that there is no other version of common-logging lingering around in your ant build path.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have posted the contents of Eclipse's `.classpath` metadata file, which defines the classpath that Eclipse uses when building your project *within Eclipse*, but you also mention using `build.xml` which implies you are also using Ant to build the project externally from the IDE.

Make sure your `<javac>` tasks in `build.xml` also refer to `commons-logging.jar`; the `.classpath` file will not be used by Ant unless you have somehow configured the build script to do so (possibly by generating build.xml from Eclipse).

Comment: They do seem to refer to commons-logging.jar as well. I posted the build.xml file into the question for reference.